# UIView height not adjusting to subview heights in UITableView header

Tags: ios, constraints, xcode7

I have a UITableView with a header view and a custom row. The header view height is not adjusting properly to the constrained heights of its subviews.

The header view container view has the following subviews with constrained heights:

- View **(this height should compute to 188 but is 128 instead)**

  - Map: UIImage (height = 128)
  - View: UIView (height = 60)

[image]

The header view height should be computed at Map Height + View Height = 128 + 60 = 188 as shown in Storyboard. However running this in the simulator squishes the header view to 128 like this:

[image]

Further inspection shows the header view height is 128 and not 188 as expected:

[image]

Also the Debug area shows a constraint conflict which shows the header view height is trying to be 128 which conflicts with the heights of its subviews. As a result it squishes the map height:

```
2015-11-27 16:58:46.415 MyApp[3387:52799] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
    Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. 
    Try this: 
        (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; 
        (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. 
    (Note: If you're seeing NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraints that you don't understand, refer to the documentation for the UIView property translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints) 
(
    "<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x7fcb5acf1270 h=--& v=--& V:[UIView:0x7fcb5c246620(128)]>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fcb5c24c440 V:[Stop Details Container]-(0)-|   (Names: Stop Details Container:0x7fcb5c24c490, '|':UIView:0x7fcb5c246620 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fcb5c24c6f0 V:[Map]-(0)-[Stop Details Container]   (Names: Stop Details Container:0x7fcb5c24c490, Map:0x7fcb5c24aa10 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fcb5c24c830 V:|-(0)-[Map]   (Names: Map:0x7fcb5c24aa10, '|':UIView:0x7fcb5c246620 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fcb5c24c880 V:[Map(128)]   (Names: Map:0x7fcb5c24aa10 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fcb5c24c8d0 V:[Stop Details Container(60)]   (Names: Stop Details Container:0x7fcb5c24c490 )>"
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fcb5c24c880 V:[Map(128)]   (Names: Map:0x7fcb5c24aa10 )>

Make a symbolic breakpoint at UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints to catch this in the debugger.
The methods in the UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in <UIKit/UIView.h> may also be helpful.
```

How can I have the header view height properly compute to the heights of its subviews?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to force the height of the tableViewHeader I had to manually edit the height property in my Storyboard file with a text editor and this did the trick.

[image]

This is most certainly a bug in Xcode 7.1.